# Error using keyAdapter and keyEvent in java

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

I'm a beginner in programming and I have been working on a small project, the well known game called Tetris and I came upon this little problem and I would like you to help me with a solution. I imported : `import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter` and
`import java.awt.event.KeyEvent` to be able to use my keyboard to play the game, but when I'm extending the class that I created to use the keys, it showing me an error!!

Here is the code:

```
addKeyListener(new TAdapter());
```

The error happens here saying this:

```
The method addKeyListener(keyListener) in the type Component is not applicable for the arguments(Board.TAdapter)
```

class TAdapter extends keyAdapter { // The second happens here: keyAdapter cannot be //resolved to a type
        public void keyPressed(keyEvent e) { // The third happens here: keyEvent //cannot be resolved to a type

```
        if (!isStarted || curPiece.getShape() == Tetrominoes.NoShape) {
            return;

        }

        int keycode = e.getKeyCode();

        if (keycode == 'p' || keycode == 'P') {
            pause();
            return;

        }
        if (isPaused)
        {return;}

    switch (keycode) {
        case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
            tryMove(curPiece, curX - 1, curY);
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
            tryMove(curPiece, curX + 1, curY);
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
            tryMove(curPiece.rotateRight(), curX, curY);
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
            tryMove(curPiece.rotateLeft(), curX, curY);
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_SPACE:
            dropDown();
            break;
        case 'd': 
            oneLineDown();
            break;
        case 'D':
            oneLineDown();
            break;

    }
  }
```

Comment: whatever the spelling: don't use keyEvent/listeners at all. Instead, use keyBindings via actionMap/inputMap

Answer (score 2):

You should avoid `KeyListener`s, they have a number of issues related to focus, they can also bloat your code and make the management more difficult.

You should instead, take advantage of the [Key Bindings API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), which provide a more reusable API and provide the means to determine the level of focus a component needs in order to recieve key events

Answer (score 0):

Use `KeyAdapter` instead of `keyAdapter`, and `KeyEvent` instead of `keyEvent`. The class names are case sensitive.

```
class TAdapter extends KeyAdapter
```

Comment: I didn't pay attention .  Thank you