# No Keyboard input java

Tags: java

I just started coding and I've studied and watched some tutorials and I finally decided to start working in my own game which is something small. The problem now is I'm not getting any type of keyboard input while running my game. I added a key listener in my game class and everything, but my players won't move. I've looked over my code several times but I cannot find the reason why I don't have any type of key input. I watched a tutorial on how to get key input and it was working for the guy in the video but it won't work for me. The game will start and show the "player" but I'm not able to move it.

I've tried to import the keyadapter and keyevent to my game class or change the name of the class i even copied the exact same code the guy in the tutorial did.

```
package com.tutorial.main;

import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class Hotkeys extends KeyAdapter{

    private Handler handler;

    public Hotkeys(Handler handler){
        this.handler = handler;
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
        int key = e.getKeyCode();

        //System.out.println(key);

        for(int i = 0; i < handler.object.size(); i++){
            GameObject tempObject = handler.object.get(i);

            if(tempObject.getID() == ID.Player){

            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_W) tempObject.setVelY(-5);
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_S) tempObject.setVelY(5);
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_A) tempObject.setVelX(5);
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_D) tempObject.setVelX(-5);
            }

            else if(tempObject.getID() == ID.Player2){

            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) tempObject.setVelY(-5);
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) tempObject.setVelY(5);
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) tempObject.setVelX(5);
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) tempObject.setVelX(-5);
            }
        }

    }   

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
        int key = e.getKeyCode();

        for(int i = 0; i < handler.object.size(); i++) {
            GameObject tempObject = handler.object.get(i);

            if(tempObject.getID() == ID.Player){

            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_W) tempObject.setVelY(0);
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_S) tempObject.setVelY(0);
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_A) tempObject.setVelX(0);
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_D) tempObject.setVelX(0);
            }

            else if(tempObject.getID() == ID.Player2){

            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) tempObject.setVelY(0);
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) tempObject.setVelY(0);
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) tempObject.setVelX(0);
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) tempObject.setVelX(0);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I need the "player" to move when i press w,a,s,d or up,down,right,left arrows

Comment: I would, highly, recommend that you stop using `KeyListener` and start using the [Key bindings API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) instead, which solve the basic issue you are having

Comment: Thank you @vladwoguer I will try to implement the Key bindings API. But any idea on why a Keylistener might not be working? Or is this a common problem?

Comment: The alternative was pointed by @MadProgrammer :) Java Awt is a very old technology that was replaced by Java Swing, so prefer to use Swing solutions. It is common to have this kind of issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24421043/4325878

Comment: @MiguelRodriguez it's a common problem with `KeyListener`. `KeyListener` can only generate events when the component it is registered to is focusable and has focus, something which the key bindings API will allow you to resolve

Comment: Ohh well thank you both I'll get to work now Haha you were of great help.